# Visual c++ (CLR) Acces richtextbox from a source file

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, global-variables, richtextbox

I have created a Form using c++ (CLR).
I have added a richtextbox and I need to make it visible in my source file in order to change the text from there.
So to sum it up:
I have a richtextbox in MyForm.h.I need to change the text of this richtextbox from Source.cpp.How do I do that?

***Managed to fix it by doing so:***

Creating a new function in the .cpp source file like this:

```
void TEST(System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox ^ changin)

{

    changin->Text = "TEST";
}
```

Than in the .h file

```
void TEST(System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox ^ changin);
```

*Here is when a button is pushed:*

```
private: System::Void button4_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

TEST(richTextBox4);

}
```

Where **richTextBox4** is the one that should be modified from the .cpp file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass your text through a public function in your form and there update the text.
In such way you save object encapsulation.

In your form add a method in the following manner:

In the form you have a private field:

```
private RichTextBox rtb;
```

rtb is reference to a user control containing the RichTextBox which expose the RichTextBox text property by overriding it:

```
 public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
        return rtb.Text;
        }
        set
        {
        rtb.Text = value;
        }
    }
```

then by a public method in your form you can access the RichTextBox.

```
public void SetText()
        {
            rtb.Text = "test_text";
        }
```

you can have a look on the same idea here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18178/A-Padded-Text-Box-Control

**Update** : have a look on the following example it emphasize my explanation above : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4544/Insert-Plain-Text-and-Images-into-RichTextBox-at-R

I hope it is clear enough.

Comment: Can you provide a small example? I am new to managed c++ started learning and experiencing it 2 days ago

Comment: I still can't make it work.First of all I get identifier override is undefined.And how exactly do I call (for example) richtextbox1 in the .cpp source file after doing this? That's all I need,to make the variable of the richtextbox available in my source file.Make it somehow global so I can acces it from the .cpp file. This kinda overwhelms me since,like I said,I am new to Visual c++ (CLR) and visual studio.

Comment: I tried changing the value from the .cpp file like this (Also made the richtextbox public from private) Project1::MyForm::richTextBox4->Text = "Text"; but I get this error: " a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object" and after compiling it this: ""Text' must point to class/struct/union/generic type""

Comment: Try to make it a public variable

Comment: I made it like this "public: System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox^  richTextBox4;" and I get those errors

Comment: Please follow this example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4544/Insert-Plain-Text-and-Images-into-RichTextBox-at-R